# resize a WPF grid when window maximized to same portions as the window

Tags: wpf, grid, resize

i have a basic grid in my WPF application:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Height="260" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,25,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="452">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="6"></Border>  
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

the grid is in the middle of the window.
When  i maximize the window i want the grid to auto resize itself to the size of the window and stay with the same margin that i specified.

How do i do that ? 
Do i have to calculate and resize the whole thing in the resize event?

i get from this:

[image]

to This (i dont want this):

[image]

i want the grid to resize to the same portions as it was , but for a full screen.

Comment: When you say "same portions" do you mean the exact same absolute width (25) or do you mean you want the margin to increase proportionally to the size of the screen?

Comment: no and no , i want the size of the grid to grow to the size of the new window size. i want , after i maximize the window , that the grid will look like the first image i attached but for a full maximized window. thanks :)

Comment: Hang on, are you talking about the margin or the border thickness? I don't understand what you mean. Everyone seems to have answered your question as I understand it.

Comment: Also, is the XAML you've posted the entire window contents? Do you have a canvas or some other element that would break the stretch to fit behaviour?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer , thank you for the fast response. i don't have a canvas. thi si the only code under the window tag. as i written in the other comments, i dont want the grid to stay the same size as the second image i posted, i want it to look like the first image , but for a maximized window. when i miximize the window, the grid will be resized to the size of the window (like the first image).

Comment: I just pasted the exact code given by snurre into a new window, and it maximises fine. Try it. Do have some styles or something that may be overriding the behaviour? Just try it in a brand new window.

Comment: Also lose the VerticalAlignment & HoriziontalAlignment in your code. Note that snurre's doesn't have that.

Comment: Nah, Snurre gave the correct answer even though he didn't explicitly state to remove the alignment. He deserves the points.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove Width and Height.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="24,25">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="6"></Border>  
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

e: Added a second grid to make it identical to OP

Comment: Yes it does. Lose the VerticalAlignment & HoriziontalAlignment in your code

Comment: You were right , if you take off the width and height , it works. it doidn't work because the HorizentalAlignment and verticalAlignment attributes should not be there too!

Answer (score 0):

You could host the `Grid` inside of another `Grid` with something like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Main Grid -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">

        <!-- Main Content -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

That would allow you to put all your content inside of the `Main Grid`, while maintaining a constant margin of 25 around all edges.

Comment: it doesn't work. my question is how do i resize the grid to the size of the window when the window is resized (and keep the margin)?

Comment: You don't resize the grid. By omitting the Width and Height attributes, it automatically stretches to the containing element (Window, in this case). Simply set Margin to whatever you want, and you'll have the desired result.

Comment: @Rodniko snurre is right in that you need to have omitted the `Width` and `Height` attributes. Controls in WPF automatically stretch to fill their container unless an alignment or size is specified.

Comment: no , if the grid doesn't have width and height it becomes a small red dot on the left upper corner. it also stays a red dot after i maximized the window.  i want the size of the grid to grow to the size of the new window size. i want , after i maximize the window , that the grid will look like the first image i attached but for a full maximized window.

Comment: it was the HorizontalAlignment and the verticalAlignment that caused the grid to be a dot. you were right, thak you vry much :)